# Increase JFreeChart dimensions on a jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart

I'm creating a `JFreeChart` and passing it to be displayed on a Jasper pdf report. This is my code for creating the chart

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
    null, // chart title
    null, // domain axis label
    scale + " Range", // range axis label
    dataset, // data
    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
    false, // include legend
    true, // tooltips
    false // urls
);
parameters.put("chartpath", chart.createBufferedImage(1600, 800));
```

The chart shows up very small in the pdf report and is unreadable. I tried to increase the dimensions in the above `createBufferedImage` function, but it's not working. Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably to do with the size of the element in the report itself rather than the chart that's being generated and passed as a parameter.

If you are using an  element in the jrxml, check the width and height properties.
If not, could you explain how you are using the "chartpath" property in the report?